# WebView having vulnerability even after putting Network Security Configuration file in >API 24

Tags: android, android-webview, android-network-security-config

Can any one help to remove the vulnerability in my android webview.
I already put NSC file and certificate of my website but still getting vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

override the `onReceivedSslError` method inside `setWebViewClient` with user choice to proceed.

```
 @Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireNonNull(getActivity()));
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    String message = getString(R.string.ssl_error_msg);
                    switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                        case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                            message = getString(R.string.ssl_untrusted);
                            break;
                        case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                            message = getString(R.string.ssl_expired);
                            break;
                        case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                            message = getString(R.string.ssl_host_mismatch);
                            break;
                        case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                            message = getString(R.string.ssl_not_yet_valid);
                            break;
                    }

                    message += getString(R.string.do_you_want_to_continue_anyway);
                    alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.ssl_cert_error_msg));
                    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
                    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", (dialog, which) -> {
                        // Ignore SSL certificate errors
                        handler.proceed();
                    });

                    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", (dialog, which) -> {
                        //myWebView.loadUrl(_URL);
                        handler.cancel();
                        dismiss();
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
```

Comment: will this code , remove the vulnerability in Mobile Security Scan ?

Comment: I have put  the below code still getting the same vulnerability 

        override fun onReceivedSslError(
                    view: WebView?,
                    handler: SslErrorHandler?,
                    error: SslError?
                ) {
                    handler!!.proceed()
                    //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error)
                }

Comment: Can u explain more where u getting error i m assuming it's in play console.

Comment: nope, i have put my code in online mobile app scan platform there i am getting the error.

Comment: Put this code which i posted I will remove warning.